# Change font type of some letters in a word in a Matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Say, for example, 
this is the plot I want to make with 'L' in 'LEGEND' in a different font.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
plt.legend(['LEGEND'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Currently, I Latex out the text I want to be unaffected and change the font for the whole function. Like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm
font_name = fm.FontProperties('Rage Italic').get_name()
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
plt.legend(['L$EGEND$'],prop={'family':font_name, 'size':14})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there any simpler way to do this, because, in my actual project, I had to do something like this `$($l$/w)_{sub} = 1$` to change the font of `l` throughout a code which was pretty cumbersome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that unless you use `usetex=True`, you will not be using latex, but rather matplotlib's [mathtext](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/text/mathtext.html). 
This allows you to use different kind of modifications to the font, the same known from latex, like `\mathit` for italic text etc.

You might hence opt for something like

```
ax.legend(['$\mathcal{L}\mathrm{EG}\mathit{END}$'], prop={'size':14})
```

[image]

Using true latex rendering may actually help you more here, because it would in prinpicle allow to use as many different fonts as you wish.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
plt.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [
        r'\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}',
        r'\usepackage{cyklop}' ]


fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,1,1,1,10])

tx = r'{\fontfamily{cyklop}\selectfont L}' + \
     r'{\fontfamily{bch}\selectfont E}' + \
     r'{\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont G}' + \
     r'{\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont END}'

ax.legend([tx], prop={'size':14})

plt.show()
```

[image]